# Onboard serial port for Asus P8Z77-V

Tags: asus, serial-port

So I have a sudden and unexpected need for RS-232.  My desktop machine (Asus P8Z77-V) has an onboard serial port which works in windows, but which isn't recognized at all in Ubuntu.  `setserial -g /dev/ttyS0` responds with:

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
```

The "unknown" apparently means "no driver."  This is confirmed by `dmesg | grep -i serial`, which gives only:

```
[    0.682764] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.682911] serial 00:06: disabled
```

So presumably I need to manually insert a kernel module, but I have no idea which one it would be.  Nothing obvious shows up with `lspci -v`.

Any idea which module would support my hardware?

**UPDATE**

In Windows 7, I have extracted the following information from the COM1 properties.  Does this tell you anything about the nature of the chip that's supplying the UART?

```
Hardware IDs: ACPI\PNP0501 *PNP0501 (ie, it's a 16550A-compatible COM port)
Physical Device Object name: \Device\0000007a 
DevNode status: 0180200A ....
Parent: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E44&SUBSYS_84CA1043&REV_04\3&11583659&0&F8
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to do ? are you connecting some form of development board via serial ? what cable are you using ?

Comment: Question edited to clarify that the serial port is onboard.  Ultimately trying to connect to a PLC's programming port, but that shouldn't have anything to do with my ability to see the UART with setserial.

Comment: It does have to do with using serial port because development boards often employ USB to RS232 converter to simulate UART which in that case uses /tty/USB0 and /tty/ACM0. In your case, if you are using standard UART cable it shouldnt matter. I am electrical engineering student but have no PLC access.  The only thing i can suggest is trying out different brand of cable which may be supported by the kernel

Comment: Miscommunication.  By "onboard serial port" I mean that the UART is physically on my motherboard, and the RS232 DB9 port is physically on my case.  I have tried to use PL2303 and CH340 USB-serial adapters without success -- the PLC is finicky.